# clang::ast_type_traits::DynTypedNode::get() cant infer template argument 'T'

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clang

I have this code snippet:

```
ASTContext::DynTypedNodeList NodeList = ASTC->getParents(*DRE);
ast_type_traits::DynTypedNode ParentNode = NodeList[0];
/*some code here to determine if the NodeKind is ImplicitCastExpr*/
const ImplicitCastExpr* ParentICE = ParentNode.get();
```

basically, its getting the parent of a match-node and then if its an
`ImplicitCastExpr()`, i want to get the node as one and do some further
checks.
when i try to compile the code, for `DynTypedNode::get()`, i get this:

```
mutator-lvl0.cpp:1644:30: error: no matching member function for call to 'get'
      ParentICE = ParentNode.get();
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/home/bloodstalker/llvm/llvm/llvm/tools/clang/include/clang/AST/ASTTypeTraits.h:233:12:
note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
  const T *get() const {
```

here's the declaration from the header:

```
template <typename T>
const T *get() const {
  return BaseConverter<T>::get(NodeKind, Storage.buffer);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template parameter `T` here:

```
template <typename T>
const T *get() const { ... }
```

is a *non-deduced context*. It cannot be deduced from the arguments to the function call. You're trying to call this function without providing a type for `T`, hence the error.

You will need to write:

```
const ImplicitCastExpr* ParentICE = ParentNode.get<ImplicitCastExpr>();
                                              //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```